# how to select a single row for every key

Tags: sql

I have this table `entry`:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | c1 |
| a1 | 2 | c2 |
| a1 | 3 | c3 |
| a2 | 2 | c4 |
| a2 | 5 | c5 |
| a2 | 7 | c6 |

What I want is a for every unique A, get only the first row ordered by its value on column B. Desired output is to have minimum B for each distinct key on column A, like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | c1 |
| a2 | 2 | c4 |

I know how to do this for any known key, but how do I loop over all distinct keys on column A?

```
-- for one given key
SELECT entry.*
FROM entry
WHERE entry.A = 'a2'
ORDER by entry.B
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the term "key" means.

Comment: Does your `entry` table have a defined `PRIMARY KEY` set? If not, _why not_?

Comment: _"for every unique A, get only the first row ordered by its value on column B"_ - `WITH x AS ( SELECT "A", MIN( "B" ) AS MinB FROM entry GROUP BY "A" ) SELECT * FROM entry INNER JOIN x ON x.A = entry.A AND entry.B = x.MinB`.

Comment: By `key` I mean `column A`.

Comment: Column `A` is not a `PRIMARY KEY` column because it cannot be used to identify a single row.

Comment: @Dai why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @shadowtalker That would require too much effort.

Answer (score 1):

"Desired output is to have minimum B for each distinct key on column A"

```
SELECT A,MIN(B)
FROM entry
GROUP BY A
```

Comment: This won't return the first _row_ ordered by `B`, it will return the minima of `B` and `C` separately.

Comment: I think hes looking for the min.. I'll drop the C since its not written above for more clarity. I'm also going to assume that column B is an int and column C doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains the solution provided by Dai in the comments.

The trick here is to separate this into two tasks:

1. Find some kind of set of attributes that uniquely identifies the the rows that you want.
2. Use those uniquely-identifying values to select the rows that you want.

Task 1 is easy:

```sql
SELECT a, MIN(b)
FROM entries
GROUP BY a
```

Task 2 can then be accomplished using a join:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c
FROM entries
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT a, MIN(b) AS b
  FROM entries
  GROUP BY a
) AS t
```

Consider what this join accomplishes. The inner query returns a list of `(a, b)` tuples that together uniquely identify the rows that you care about. The join then matches those `(a, b)` tuples with rows in the original `entries` table, thereby finding exactly what we are looking for.

This pattern can be used in any problem where you need to find one specific row for each group.

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` <-- _ewwww_

Comment: @Dai should have posted your own answer!

Comment: But I am laaaazzyyy - and your answer is a well-written explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

In the question you mentioned that you want the 1st row as shown in the table.

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM entry GROUP BY A
```

However if you want it in for a min of B just add a `HAVING` Clause

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM entry GROUP BY A HAVING MIN(B)
```