# Polars: fill nulls with the only vaild value within each group

Tags: python-polars

Each group only has one valid or not_null value in a random row. How do you fill each group with that value?

```py
import polars as pl

data = {
    'group': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
    'col1': [1, None, None, None, 3, None, None, None, 5],
    'col2': ['a', None, None, None, 'b', None, None, None, 'c'],
    'col3': [False, None, None, None, True, None, None, None, False]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3  │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64  ┆ str  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1    ┆ a    ┆ false │
│ 1     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null  │
│ 1     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null  │
│ 2     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null  │
│ 2     ┆ 3    ┆ b    ┆ true  │
│ 2     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null  │
│ 3     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null  │
│ 3     ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null  │
│ 3     ┆ 5    ┆ c    ┆ false │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Desired output:

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3  │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64  ┆ str  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1    ┆ a    ┆ false │
│ 1     ┆ 1    ┆ a    ┆ false │
│ 1     ┆ 1    ┆ a    ┆ false │
│ 2     ┆ 3    ┆ b    ┆ true  │
│ 2     ┆ 3    ┆ b    ┆ true  │
│ 2     ┆ 3    ┆ b    ┆ true  │
│ 3     ┆ 5    ┆ c    ┆ false │
│ 3     ┆ 5    ┆ c    ┆ false │
│ 3     ┆ 5    ┆ c    ┆ false │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

In pandas, I can do the following for each column

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.col1 = df.groupby('group').col.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

How do you do this in polars, ideally with a window function (.over()) ?

Comment: Hi @steven, a window operation with min should do it: pl.min(‘col’).over(‘group’)

Comment: @Luca hah... such a clever workaround. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The immediate way to do exactly what you asked is (and it looks the most like your pandas approach):**

```
df.with_columns(pl.exclude('group').forward_fill().backward_fill().over('group'))
```

using `pl.all()` instead of `pl.exclude('group')` also works but it'll save some theoretical time by not making it look through the `group` column for the fills.

If there's a list of columns you want to do this to (as opposed to all but `group`) then you can replace the `pl.exclude` with a generator or list comprehension

```
cols=['col1','col2','col3']
df.with_columns(pl.col(x).forward_fill().backward_fill().over('group') for x in cols)
```

You can even use regex in `pl.col` as long as you use the `^` and `$` anchor.

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("^col\d$").forward_fill().backward_fill().over('group'))
```

**Another approach besides forward/backward fills:**

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("^col\d$").drop_nulls().first().over('group'))
```

If the `first` looks a little weird it's because the `drop_nulls` is going to return a different number of rows than the original `df` which will cause an error. If the expression is an aggregation (like `sum`, `min`, `max`, etc) then it doesn't complain about getting a different number of rows and, instead, just propagates that answer to all the rows. In this case `first` is the aggregation which just means the first thing it sees. Since the filter is only returning one thing we just need a way to tell it to propagate that.

The different column selection tricks work in this approach too but I'll spare the reader the extra copy/paste

**Final note:**

if your next step is to take `unique` then you should just do it as a `df.groupby` to start with

```
df \
    .groupby('group', maintain_order=True) \
    .agg(pl.col("^col\d$").drop_nulls().first())
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to first extract the non-null rows in each group, and then join those values back into the table.

```py
import polars as pl

data = pl.DataFrame{
    'group': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
    'col': [1, None, None, None, 3, None, None, None, 5]
})

data_non_null = (
    data
    .filter(pl.col('col').is_not_null())
    .select('group', col_non_null='col')
)

data = (
    data
    .join(data_non_null, on='group')
    .select('group', col='col_non_null')
)
```

This is an application of a [very general pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75728402/2954547) that should also work in Pandas, SQL, the various R data frame libraries, etc.

Note that usually you need some kind of grouping operation to apply this pattern. Here however we know/assume that there is exactly one non-null value in each group, so we just have to filter for non-null values.

Comment: This indeed works, but i wonder if there is a window function way...